# Display every other element in an Array

Tags: javascript

How do I display every other element in an Array?
My code is as follows:

```js
var tall = ["1", "2", "3","4","5","11","15"];
    
    for (var i = 1; i<=15; i++) {
        if (i%2 === 0) {
            document.getElementById("tall").innerHTML += i + "<br/>";
        }
    }
```

```html
<div id="tall"></div>
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking; please explain where/how this function is supposed to be called, and what exactly the desired result is.

Comment: No one would laugh at other peoples code, everyone has to start some where. this smells alot like homework tho. have you tryed some things ? if so could you add them to the question ?

Comment: running `tall(3)` displays every other item in your array. Not sure what the issue is exactly

Comment: I want to display every other/second element in an Array, such as 2, 4, 11.

Comment: I just now realized that "nummer" 1 or 2 is independent from your problem. Next time, only share code that is relevant to your problem, in this example the for loop and the array itself.

Comment: I thought it could be relevant, but thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you overcomplicated things a bit, from the looks of it. Here's how to get every other element of an array:

```js
 var tall = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
 
 for(var i = 0; i < tall.length; i += 2) {
     console.log(tall[i]);
 }
```

You just use your usual for-loop, but increase `i` by `2` for every iteration.

EDIT: The only mistake you made was to add `i` to the HTML-object instead of `tall[i]` and to loop until `15` instead of `tall.length`.

Here a copy of your code fixed:

```js
var tall = ["1", "2", "3","4","5","11","15"];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < tall.length; i++) {
        if (i%2 === 0) {
            document.getElementById("tall").innerHTML += tall[i] + "<br/>";
        }
    }
```

```html
<div id="tall"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The number 1 and 2 is correct but for 3 you put === insted of ==

```js
if (nummer == 3) {
    for (var i = 1; i<=15; i++) {
        if (i%2 == 0) {
            document.getElementById("tall").innerHTML += i + "<br/>";
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: insted of i< 15  change it  to i< tell.length

Comment: There is nothing wrong with === here, the problem lies with him addin "i" instead of "tall[i]".